# Discord bot not playing audio file (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, discord, bots

I'm trying to play local audio files. If I type in the filesource, the audio plays, but if I make it from strings, it doesn't.

```
    case prefix + '1':
    {
    
  //var s = './Audio/file.wav';             this works
    var s = './Audio/' + textByLine[0];   //textByLine[0] is 'file.wav'
    
    isReady = false;
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>
    {
    var dispatcher = connection.play(s);
    })
    isReady = true;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: put a `console.log(s);` under `var s = './Audio/' + textByLine[0];`

Comment: What does it say ?! I bet something like "./audio/undefined" or "./audio//file.wav" there is absolut no logical reason that this does not work when the path is correct.

Comment: https://imgur.com/6HqR3zx

Comment: Use a `util.inspect` to see if there are any hidden chars or so. And im not sure but `/` are not valid on windows. Use `path.normalize` to be sure.

Comment: it had \r at the end
Thx for the help